# Confusion on two tensors constructed from Riemann curvature tensor and its dual

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, terminology, curvature

Assuming the metric signature is $(-+++)$ and solves vacuum Einstein equation, we start from Riemann curvature tensor $R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$ and its dual ${}^*\!R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$ and construct following things:
$$\begin{align}
A_{\lambda\tau \mu \nu} &= {}^*\!R_{\lambda\tau}{}^{\rho\sigma}R_{\mu \nu\rho\sigma }\\
B_{\lambda\tau \mu \nu} &= R_{\lambda\tau}{}^{\rho\sigma}R_{\mu \nu\rho\sigma }
\end{align}$$

What are the names of these quantities? Are they antisymmetric on their indices?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what those tensors are called, but when contracting their indices as
\begin{align}
& g^{\lambda\mu}g^{\tau\nu}A_{\lambda\tau\mu\nu}=* R_{\lambda\tau\mu\nu}R^{\lambda\tau\mu\nu}~,\\
& g^{\lambda\mu}g^{\tau\nu}B_{\lambda\tau\mu\nu}=R_{\lambda\tau\mu\nu}R^{\lambda\tau\mu\nu}~,
\end{align}
the former is the so-called 4d gravitational Chern-Simons term studied [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0308071) for example. The latter is part of Gauss-Bonnet gravity (and other modified gravity models).

$A$ and $B$ are both antisymmetric in their first two and last two indices due to their definition.